# Is unlocking all the items enough for the Golden God achievement?

Tags: achievements, the-binding-of-isaac

Is Golden God unlocked by *unlocking* every non-DLC item, or do you need to also *find and pick them up*?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you must collect all the items in addition to unlocking them in order to get Golden God.

I unlocked this achievement after completing Challenge 1 in Wrath of the Lamb after picking up the (very dreadfully bad) Dead Cat item after a boss fight (?!). Sure, completing the challenge *unlocked* the Candle — but that's a DLC item, so it doesn't count.

Comment: Although, to be fair, I still haven't collected the wafer... could it be a bug with the game? I dunno.

Comment: Did you obtain three Guppy items and turn into Guppy yourself? There's the "Guppys Hairball" achievement for that, but I don't know if that is an addition of WotL

Comment: @Zommuter It is a WotL-only thing. No, I didn't turn into Guppy.

Comment: too bad, looks cute :-7

Answer (score 2):

*Unlocking* all non-DLC items is the condition to get Golden God. I got the Golden God achievement as soon as I unlocked the last non-DLC item.